An issue with the boot menu in MacBook M3 ARM 86 to install Ubuntu
My ARM86 M3 MacBook doesn't display the boot menu, so I can't install  Ubuntu. I tried booting from both USB and DVD, but none of the key combinations (Command + R, P, and Option, or Power) worked. What can I do to access the boot menu and install Ubuntu Server?


Welcome to AskUbuntu. An M3 Mac may not be the best choice for Ubuntu Server as the Apple architecture is not supported by that OS. If you need Ubuntu Server on the machine, it would be better to run it as a VM or within a Docker container.

Thank you for your response. I want to have it as an operation system.

If you want a bare metal installation, then you will need to take a look at Asahi Linux, as Ubuntu does not support Apple Silicon. There is also very, very limited support for the M3. It may be reverse engineered some time next year, but the team behind the project is stretched a little thin.

Thank you for the advice. It seems like Asahi Linux is the best option for now to install directly on Apple Silicon. Hopefully, the development team will be able to improve support soon and things will get better.
